# Sending images from form with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been working on a form where you upload an image and a comment. I got it working in PHP, but now I'd like to do it in AJAX. The reason I'd like to do it in AJAX is because the user has to type all of their text again when the upload fails (due to conditions like: fields can't be empty or the aspect ratio of the image is off). However whatever I do, I fail to do it in AJAX.

I've tried to do it in FormData, with $.post and with $.ajax. I've also looked up a lot of guides, and other posts about this, but nothing seems to work for me.

Below you will find the HTML form, the jQuery AJAX call and the PHP code from the PHP page the AJAX call calls.

HTML FORM

```
<form action="uploadpost.php" id="postForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="postImage">Upload image</label>
            <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="postImage" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Write a caption</label>
            <textarea name="description" id="postMessage" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="postSubmit" value="Create post" name="upload_image" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

The AJAX call

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#postSubmit").on("click", function(e){
        var formData = new FormData($("#postForm"));
        //var message = $("#postMessage").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/postUpload.php", 
            type: "POST",             
            data: formData,             
            contentType: "multipart/form-data",       
            cache: false,             
            processData:false,        
            success: function(data)  
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The PHP code in ajax/postUpload.php

```
<?php
include_once("../classes/Post.class.php");
$post = new Post();

var_dump($_FILES);
if(!empty($_POST)){

$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['postImage']['tmp_name'];


$result = $post->createPost($file_tmp_name);
if($result){
    $uploadCheck['check'] = "success";
}else{
    $uploadCheck['check'] = "error";    
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($uploadCheck);
}

?>
```

Output from `console.log(data)` on ajax call return

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
<i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>
```

The problem is that I can't send the image nor the message over to that PHP page, which doesn't allow me to do `createPost()`.

Comment: Sidenote on Stacks new color code scheme; it sucks. Man.. 2 shades of blue for HTML forms? Who came up with that idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var formData = new FormData($("#postForm"));
> ```

The argument to FormData should be a DOM form object, not a jQuery object.

```
new FormData($("#postForm")[0])
```

---

Setting the content type manually:

> contentType: "multipart/form-data",

… will fail to set the boundary data in it. Say:

```
contentType: false,
```

… so that jQuery won't try to set it at all and the XHR object will generate it from the FormData object.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I've tested it out, however the console.log(data) still gives me the same output. The array is still empty.

Comment: Yeah I've tried setting it to false before, the output remains the same, maybe it's something on the PHP side in postUpload?

Comment: It's getting to the point where I'd really start hitting the browser's developer tools and examining exactly what the request was.

Comment: I got it, I made a silly mistake, my false was "false" instead. now I got a new problem, but I think I can handle that on my own. Thanks alot!